# "Cannot update during an existing state transition" Error in React Native and Redux with External API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, dispatch

I am writing a React Native app and using Redux.

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mlwjZL3Fmw&t=55s) tutorial.

I have faced with the following warning message:

Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render' or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'

Here is what I have:

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { login } from './actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'native-base';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.login("username","password")}>
          <Text>
            Login!
          <Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { state: state.login }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './configureStore';
import Route from './config/Router';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let store = configureStore();
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyComponent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore() {
  let store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
  return store;
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
import * from './constants'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  isLoggingIn: false,
  username: '',
  error: false
};

function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log('Reducer is called.');
  console.log('Action is ' + JSON.stringify(action));
  console.log('state is ' + JSON.stringify(state));
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGGING_IN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        isLoggingIn: true,
        username: '',
        error: false
      }
    case LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        isLoggingIn: false,
        username: action.data.username,
        error: false
      }
    case LOG_IN_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        isLoggingIn: false,
        username: '',
        error: true
      }
   }
}

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducer,
});
```

**actions.js**

```
import * './constants'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export function login(username, password) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loggingIn())
    //here will be some API ASYNC CALLS! 
    //depending on the result we will dispatch again!
    myService.login(username,password).done((result) => {
      if(result !== null) {
        dispatch(loginSuccess(result))
      } else {
        dispatch(loginFailure())
      }
    })
  }
}

function loggingIn() {
  return {
    type: LOGGING_IN
  }
}

function loginSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: LOG_IN_SUCCESS,
    data: data
  }
}

function loginFailure() {
  return {
    type: LOG_IN_FAILURE
  }
}
```

I have debugged the code. I have seen that the warning comes right after first dispatch call! ( dispatch(loggingIn()) )

So, I don't know what the problem is.

I also wonder if this is the true use of redux and async api calls. Can you help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think something wrong here

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { state: state.login }
}
```

Should be

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { loginReducer: state.loginReducer }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall from my experience, **this error** usually appears when you are trying **to update** something in your **render method**, which is prohibited.

Verify that it is not happening in your app.

**UPD:** Try creating **a function above** the render method that calls **this.props.login** instead of doing it inside **mapDispatchToProps.** And add your the **login** action creator instead of mapDispatchToProps as a **second argument** to the **connect** function.